# Symfony2/DC2/PHP: prevent the user from creating someone elses entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the entities Floor and LeaseTerm. Floor can have many LeaseTerms.

In my LeaseTerm CREATE form, I have a hidden floor_id field.

My question is: how can i effectively prevent the user from changing the floor_id field himself and creating LeaseTerms for floors he doesnt own (each floor has it's owner)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually the 'how' is to validate the floor_id upon submission, ensuring that the current user owns/has access to the floor. Theoretically even if they do change it, so long as it's still an id they have access to, the operation is probably still valid (if not, additional validations on the submission context would be necessary).

In Symfony 2 as a specific implementation this could be achieved with the logic directly in a controller, or perhaps alternatively with help from a '[Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)' and/or [Custom Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, in the context of Symfony 2, I would have to compare logged in users_id and $floor->getOwner()->getId()? If they don't match, I guess a good idea would be to throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea :). You would probably want to throw an exception yes - you could then later handle an 'Input Exception' or whatever you would care to call it with some kind of 403 Forbidden, 404, or some other custom response.